# How can I populate a grid with a count of how many times an item is not null in a child object?

Tags: angularjs

I have two objects. A `Word` object that contains a list of `WordForm` objects. Here are the typescript interface files that show the objects and their fields:

```
interface IWord {
    wordForms: IWordForm[];
    wordId: string;
}

interface IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    sample1: string;
    sample2: string;
    sample3: string;
    sample4: string;
    sample5: string;
}
```

I have a report that I create like this:

```
   <div ng-class="{current: row.current}"
         ng-class-even="'even'"
         ng-class-odd="'odd'"
         ng-click="wos.wordsRowClicked(row)"
         ng-dblclick="wos.wordsRowDoubleClicked(row)"
         ng-repeat="row in wos.wordsView = (wos.words | orderBy:wos.wordsOrderBy[wos.wordsOrderById].key:wos.wordsSortDirectionId == 1)">
        <div>
            <div>{{ row.wordId }}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>{{ row.wordForms.length }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Rather than report on the number of WordForms for each word, I would like to show a report that shows a count for the number of non-null sample sentences.

So for example here's what I have now. It shows that cat has one Wordform but doesn't show if any of the sample sentences are populated:

```
WordId      Wordform Count
hello       2
dog         2
cat         1
```

Here's what I would like. No longer a count of Wordforms per row but a count of the number of sample sentences in each Wordform with a comma separator:

```
WordId      Wordform Sample Sentence counts
hello       1, 3
dog         2, 4
cat         4
```

In this case it would show that:

- "hello" word has one wordform with 1 sample sentence and one with three sample sentences
- "cat" word has one wordform with 4 sample sentences.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this with AngularJs?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a function that generates the counts for you. At first, I was going to suggest another ng-repeat that goes over the wordforms, but that would make not having a trailing comma in your list difficult.

You'll want to change your html to something like this:

```
   <div ng-class="{current: row.current}"
     ng-class-even="'even'"
     ng-class-odd="'odd'"
     ng-click="wos.wordsRowClicked(row)"
     ng-dblclick="wos.wordsRowDoubleClicked(row)"
     ng-repeat="row in wos.wordsView = (wos.words | orderBy:wos.wordsOrderBy[wos.wordsOrderById].key:wos.wordsSortDirectionId == 1)">
    <div>
        <div>{{ row.wordId }}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>{{ row.wordFormsString() }}</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Then, you'll need to have a function on your row to generate this list that would loop over the wordForms. The function would probably call a function on each wordForm that would return the number of sample sentences. Then append that to the string that it'd return, and finally comma if there are any more left to loop over.

---

This would actually be easier if the samples were an array. Then the function on row would only have to loop, appending the array length of the wordForm to the return string. For example, you'd change your interfaces to be like this:

```
interface IWord {
    wordForms: IWordForm[];
    wordId: string;
}

interface IWordForm {
    definition: string;
    samples: string[];
}
```

Then the function would do this:

```
function () {
    var strReturn = '';

    for (var wordForm of row.wordForms) {
        if (strReturn !== '') {
            strReturn += ', ';
        }
        strReturn += wordForm.samples.length;
    }
    return strReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Unfortunately samples were code as columns in a table. Do you think it would be possible for me to code in a function the adding of sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4 and sample5 to an array at the start of the function?

Comment: The reason I mentioned moving it to an Array was because the function to iterate over different keys would be ugly. And it would be just as ugly to write something that will add these to an array. Basically, you'll have to either have your for loop do something like `if (wordForm.sample1) { <concat>}
if (wordForm.sample2) { <concat> } etc` Or you could do something like a loop with an incremented number that you use to access each sample... like `var i = 1; while i <= 5 { if (wordForm['sample' + i) { <concat>;} i++;}`